# Add 10 different UIImages in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to add various `UIImages` under `UIImageView` and allow them to scroll with `UIScrollView`. I am not sure how to add various images under `UIImageView` and let them scroll.
Below is my code which adds an image on `UIImageView` and make it scrollable.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ae.jpg"];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    imageView.contentMode = (UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit);
    imageView.autoresizingMask = ( UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];



    UIScrollView* scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    scrollView.contentMode = (UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit);

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(image.size.width,960);
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = NO;
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
    scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = NO;
    scrollView.autoresizingMask = ( UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 2.5;
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1;
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
   [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
   [image release];
    [imageView release];
   [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
}
```

Comment: You probably want to use multiple UIImageViews in the same UIScrollView. But it's unclear exactly what you want it to do.

Comment: I want to add various images one below the other like want to add another image below "ae.png" and allow it to scroll. Lets say currently it has only one image, but if I want to add an array of images in UIIImageView, is it possible ?

Comment: Just use multiple UIImageViews.

Comment: ok. But then how would you determine the position of the image programmatically ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idea is basically simple. Let's assume you want to place 3 images in UIScrollView.
Each of images is 300x300. In this case you'll have scroll view with frame:

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(image.size.width,900);
```

For every image you must have it's UIImageView with proper frame:

```
imgView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, 300, 300)];
imgView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 300, 300, 300)];
imgView3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 600, 300, 300)];
imgView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ProperName.png"];
...
```

(pay attention to the yOrigin (2nd value in CGRectMake))
and then as you did:

```
[scrollView addSubview:imgView1];
[scrollView addSubview:imgView2];
[scrollView addSubview:imgView3];
[imgView1 release];
[imgView2 release];
[imgView3 release];
```

Of course, it's a brief code, you'll optimize it ;)

Comment: what kind of optimization do you suggest ? Becouause with 20 uiviews, each one containing 1 UIImageview (with shadow and border) and 2 UILabels (without text effect), my UIScrollView doesn't scroll smoothly.

Comment: Well, I haven't collided with that kind of problem, but I would try to implement some page reuse algorithm (UITableView takes this approach for cell reuse). That way in memory you'll always have a limited amount of pages (and their resources accordingly). Obviously, you'll have to fill in the content in a dynamic way when scrolling. You can read my answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374907/uiscrollview-selection-like-uipickerview look through the part n.2 of the answer). There you'll get one of the possible ideas of how to spare memory. Good luck.