# Inserting images in to a horizontal scroll view in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios5

I am developing a **camera app** right now and am using **image filter effects** for the pictures that I take. So, when I take a picture, the picture should be shown and below that, I want to show ten different filter effects of that picture in the form of a **horizontal scroll view**.

So, if I click any one of the filter effects in the scroll view, that particular effect should get applied to the picture that I've taken and that **filter applied picture** should get displayed in the same view. I should also have a save button above the picture, so that I can save it in my **private app directory**. (**Note:** Not in the default image gallery)

I couldn't figure out the exact code or the concept that I have to implement as how to insert the images in a horizontal scroll view or how to save the picture in to my private app directory. I am using iOS5. So, any good solution for this is much appreciated.

Comment: Which part do you need help with?  Do you know how to display images on the screen?  Do you know how to put images in a scroll view?  Do you know how to apply a filter to an image?  Do you know how to put a button on the screen?  Do you know how to write an image to a file?  Be specific about what you need help with.  If you don't know how to do *any* of those things, then you need to work through some tutorials.

Comment: You should try googling your issue before posting on SO. This I got in under 3 seconds. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6876334/593336

Comment: @robmayoff: I couldnt figure out the exact code or the concept that i have to implement as how to insert the images in a horizontal scroll view or how to save the picture in to my private app directory

Comment: @mayuur: Also if i click any one of those filter effect applied images in the h.scroll view, will that picture be showed in full screen?

Comment: As @mayuur said a simple google search would of solved these problems; 1. Add Custom UIButton to UIScrollView, 2. Save Camera Image to app directory. In terms of inserting the UIButtons horizontally, you should go back to basic algorithms if you can't figure this out

Comment: Search properly before asking questions if you still got problem, then don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: @CStreel: So, i have to insert a scroll view inside the main view, then insert 10 image views for the filter effect pictures and inside each of those imageviews, i have to add buttons, so that if i click on the picture, the action will be to show the clicked picture in full screen. Is that what u r saying?

Comment: @AjitKumar No, don't insert imageviews, insert UIButtons. Google "UIButton with image".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be helps you for horizontal scrollview images.

```
int scrollWidth = 180;
scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth,110);    
int xOffset = 4;

for(int i = 0; i < [imgnamearr count]; ++i) 
{   
    UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    img.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    img.frame = CGRectMake(5+xOffset,1, 145, 110);
    scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth+xOffset,115); 
    [img addSubview:[UIImage imageNamed:[imgnamearr objectAtIndex:i]]];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(5+xOffset,0, 160, 110);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.accessibilityIdentifier =[imgarr objectAtIndex:i]; 
    [scrollview addSubview:img];
    [scrollview addSubview:button];
    scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth+xOffset,115);
    xOffset += 157;
}

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
   UIImageView *bigimg = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
   bigimg.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
   bigimg.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 200, 200);
   [bigimg addSubview:[UIImage imageNamed:sender.accessibilityIdentifier]];
   [self.view addSubview:bigimg];
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
-(void)Setthewholeview{

int row = 0;
int column = 0;


for(int i = 0; i < [imagearry count]; ++i) 
{

    UIView *uview =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(column*155+5, row*126, 155, 125)];
    uview.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    uview.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];



    UIImageView *detailback =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,72,52,52)]; 
    detailback.image=[[UIImage alloc]init];
    detailback.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"];
    [uview addSubview:detailback];
    [detailback release];


    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(column*155+5, row*126, 155, 125);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.tag = [[arrayname objectAtIndex:i]intValue]; 

    if (column == 1) // here set column which you want. If you wnat 2 column then set 1 here.
    {
        column = 0;
        row++;
    } else 
    {
        column++;
    }

    [self.scrollview addSubview:uview];
    [self.scrollview addSubview:button];
}

[self.scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, (row+1) * 130)];

}
```

Comment: If i click any of the picture in the scroll view, will it display the picture in full screen? Or else, what action will be performed?

Comment: For display in full screen you have to write further code in it and take another view in it for display bigimage.

Comment: No, i want to display the picture in full screen in the same view, if i click on it. Do, i have to insert any custom button inside the scroll- image view?

Comment: Don't use UIImage or UIImageView, instead use a UIButton and set it's image

Answer (score 2):

You can make a scroll view scroll only horizontally by setting the height of its `contentSize` equal to the height of its `bounds`.

You can show images in a scroll view by adding instances of `UIImageView` as subviews of the scroll view.

You can use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` or `UIImagePNGRepresentation` to convert an image to an `NSData`, and write the data by sending it the `writeToURL:options:error:` message.

You can get the URL of your app's private documents directory using `-[NSFileManager URLForDirectory:inDomain:appropriateForURL:create:error:]`, passing `NSDocumentDirectory` as the directory, `NSUserDomainMask` as the domain, and `nil` as the URL.